# Checking if two columns in MySQL table are equal is too slow

Tags: mysql

I have an SQL table of the following form:

```
| DateID | StartDate | EndDate  | a lot more columns...
|--------|-----------|----------|----------------------
|    1   |2017-02-09 |2017-02-16| ...
|    2   |2017-02-10 |   NULL   | ...
|    3   |2017-02-08 |2017-02-08| ...
```

I often run Querys like:

```
SELECT * FROM Dates
WHERE (EndDate IS NULL AND StartDate<='some date') OR
      (StartDate=EndDate AND StartDate>='some date' AND (other conditions))
```

Because the table contains several thousand records, this query is rather slow. Is there a way to speed this up? For example using a view that only contains those dates that have the same StartDate and EndDate?
StartDate and EndDate are already defined as indexes, but that doesn't help with the "StartDate=EndDate" part I guess.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Try to create 2 querys to avoid `or`

Comment: Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.
 
 [**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: MySQL index [**TIPS**](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

Comment: Sorry, I'm quiet new to MySQL, I will have to read a bit more about EXPLAIN ANALYSE (and a lot of other things).
And I will definately give that article you linked a read! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OR is your issue. Because of it, MySQL can't rely on the date indexes and take another (bad) path or even worst, do a full table scan.

The general solution to overcome this kind of problems is to mimic the `OR` by UNIONing several queries.

```
SELECT * FROM Dates WHERE (EndDate IS NULL AND StartDate<='some date') 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM Dates WHERE (StartDate=EndDate AND StartDate>='some date' AND (other conditions))
```

For each of these queries, MySQL should properly use the indexes, which will speed up the total execution time by an enormous factor.

`OR` is generally evil in SQL and should be avoided when possible.

Comment: Thanks, I will definately try that!
But what about the "StartDate=EndDate"? Doesn't MySQL have to do a full table scan for this?

Comment: No, IF you have properly indexed both columns.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks for the help! I found out that the real problem wasn't even the `OR` in my query (though I optimized it now using the advice of Thomas G), but it was a not-so-optimal using of indexes in another table used in a `JOIN`.

So thanks to Juan Carlos Oropeza for providing the link to the [MySQL indexing tips!](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)